# Can I test more than two variable (specifically three) in a for loop?

Tags: python, database, sorting, for-loop, variables

previously I made a code that tested the variables `my_list[x]` and `my_list[x+1]` in a for loop. I was wondering if I could do the same with three variables (I was thinking `my_list[x+2]` but I don't think thats working). For reference, I used `my_list[x]` and `my_list[x+1]` to look for certain conditions in a data set and now I need to add a third. Thanks!

Comment: Amm of course you can...

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. Could you provide some code as an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can. The only this to avoid index error is:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    print (l[i])

for i in range(len(l)-1):
    print (l[i])
    print (l[i+1])

for i in range(len(l)-2):
    print (l[i])
    print (l[i+1])
    print (l[i+2])
```

Etc...